# how can I remove small gap vertically

Tags: html, css

If I remove the space between the block code it only removes a small gap horizontally,
but vertically it's still has a small gap i know i can use flexbox instead but, I'm trying to understand why it behaves like this, any idea why it still has a small gap? vertically it can be removed with font size set to 0 but there is no text or letter below the image

[image]

```css
/* Video Wrapper */

.video-wrapper {
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.video-wrapper > h2 {
  text-indent: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.video-content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-wrapper > p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
No Space Removed:


<section class="video-wrapper" id="video-section">
  <h2>Video</h2>
  <div class="video-content"></div>
  <p>Carefully Haa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non perspiciatis veritatis veniam hic dignissimos! Et quas magnam doloremque, sapiente quae error ut repellendus esse aspernatur doloribus mollitia sunt iste cupiditate quisquam, aliquam dolorem labore dolore nobis repellat consectetur vel, nulla harum alias incidunt. Odit, dolorem. Maiores maxime quidem quis odit?</p>
</section>


Space Removed :

<section class="video-wrapper" id="video-section"><h2>Video</h2><div class="video-content"></div><p>Carefully Haa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non perspiciatis veritatis veniam hic dignissimos! Et quas magnam doloremque, sapiente quae error ut repellendus esse aspernatur doloribus mollitia sunt iste cupiditate quisquam, aliquam dolorem labore dolore nobis repellat consectetur vel, nulla harum alias incidunt. Odit, dolorem. Maiores maxime quidem quis odit?</p></section>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the space around the paragraph in the dark blue box? It's not clear.

Comment: Inline elements leave a small gap for descender text elements like j, y, g. Changing the vertical alignment resolves the gap.

Comment: Give this person some slack. English might not be his first language...Anyways look into `flexbox` as you can give each child `flex:1` to have them be same height.

Comment: @j08691 i see the box got treated as text so it has descender thus cause the blank gap that's why font size set to 0 solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reducing the margin-Bottom you can hide or remove the gap

to do that CSS will be

```
.video-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as answered @Jvs there is a way like to reduce margin-botttom and
there is more one way  is reducing height of parent tag/class

in your case CSS :

```
.video-wrapper {
    background-color: royalblue;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 450px;
}
```

Try this one also :p